# Using conditionals in javascript template literal

Tags: javascript

I store a value in my localstorage and based on that value I would like to decide the styling inside a template literal notation.

here I have some variables:

```
var right = localStorage.getItem("shareBarPosition") === "right";
var posRight = `#socialShare {
  left: auto;
  right: 0 !important;
}`;

var posLeft = `#socialShare {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: auto;
}`;
```

which I would like to use in a template literal notation like this:

```
document.querySelector("#shareButton-code").innerHTML += `<style>
    /* Button specific styling */
    ${right ? posRight : posLeft}
</style>`
```

But this will always show the posRight styling. Why is that?

Comment: Why don't you do it in JavaScript and add a `document.querySelector("#shareButton-code").innerHTML += ...` inside an `if` followed by another to close the script?

Comment: @phuzi lol ofcourse -.-''

Comment: Writing CSS with a template? Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Yes you can put a conditional operator in a template interpolation, but you are currently missing the else (`:`) part.

Comment: @Bergi could you show me a simple example?

Comment: your example should work, are you sure you are resetting the "shareBarPosition" before you refresh using onbeforeunload or something?

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin yes it is triggered after a button click

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin and the value of shareBarPosition is updated but it always renders true variant

Comment: I cannot replicate this, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/7ojp8u4g/

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I replicated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7ojp8u4g/26/  But this is working hahah

Comment: still does not replicate. http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/7ojp8u4g/37/ . Even with += operator. I think, you just forgot to 'extend' the textBox........

Comment: @Sireini You've just completely changed the question by swapping out the question. The mistake is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the `innerHTML +=` to `innerHTML =`

```
document.querySelector("#shareButton-code").innerHTML = `<style>
  /* Button specific styling */
  ${!right ? posLeft : posRight}
</style>`
```

Comment: += works too, you didn't extend the textbox to see the rest, did you?

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin but it has to replace the previous styling rules